# Is a restore button required for Auto-renewing subscription if the subscription is managed on a user account?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

In WWDC 2013 they mentioned that a restore button is required for Auto-renewing subscriptions.

[image: restore from wwdc]

However, in our model, subscriptions are managed though a user account.  Restoring is done by logging in to the account.  The receipts are stored on our server.

Having a restore button will not actually do anything, but would leaving it out risk rejection?

Comment: what were your findings? Need to know exactly the same. Thanks.

Comment: @iAmd - Never got the answer I am afraid - we ended up going for a non renewing subscription.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524733/is-restore-button-necessary-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions solution useful? I am also stuck to same issue. Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Yogesh.Lolusare.Apple , we went for auto-renewable subscriptions in our application WITHOUT restore button and the application got accepted. All we did was, we presented a good case in the Review Notes specifying why we don't need a restore button whilst submitting the application and that was it. I have answered the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524733/is-restore-button-necessary-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions

Comment: Great. Thank You for your valuable inputs.