# Is restore button necessary for Auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, auto-renewing

Exactly the same question as
[this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002582/is-a-restore-button-required-for-auto-renewing-subscription-if-the-subscription)

I understand that restore button is necessary so when user upgrades the phone, the user is able to get back the contents/services subscribed earlier.
In our application we require users to login. Once they login, they have to subscribe to use the services of the application. From user's credentials we are keeping track that which users are still subscribed to our application. So when user changes the phone and logs in with his/her credentials there is no need for a restore button as we will verify at the time of login if this user is subscribed to our services or not.

From the forums and developer documents, its evident that I have to add a restore button but whats the sense here and where should I place the restore button as when the user logs in to a new device, he/she is already able to use the app with subscription?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We went for auto-renewable subscriptions in our application WITHOUT restore button and the application got accepted. All we did was, we presented a good case in the Review Notes specifying why we don't need a restore button whilst submitting the application and that was it.

Comment: @halbano, as i mentioned, the app got approved from Apple review and published on app store.

Comment: @iAmd can you please let us know the case you mentioned to them ?

Comment: I understand that you get the approve, but like @KeyurAkbari I'll be glad to hear your reply to the Apple team.

Comment: @halbano, don't remember exactly. Tried digging old stuff but that couldn't find. From the top of my head we mentioned how we would be managing the users purchases even if he deletes the app and installs again etc. and in the end mentioned that its the main reason we don't deem a restore button necessary.

May be the acceptance of the app was only an overlook and something which Apple really doesn't approve. We thought to just push it for review and see what happens and in the end the app did got approved.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are using Auto-renewing subscription you don't keep the "Restore" button Apple will reject your application .
2. If User has purchased a product .Then that purchase is made to the apple id not by the user id.
3. After login you can keep the Restore button.