# Restore button and end date from receipt for auto renewable IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing one commercial app (app having different tools to calculate) where I implemented auto-renewable subscriptions. I am able to test it properly.

How my app works:

1. App web services allow user to use app free for three months.
2. User is asked to get subscribe for an year to use tools.
3. Once payment is done, receipt is validate and stored at web services.
4. Once subscription period get collapsed, auto renewable subscription come to play.

My questions:

1. Is adding restore button is any way compulsory? Referring [Is restore button necessary for Auto-renewable subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524733/is-restore-button-necessary-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions), it says restore button is not required in auto subscription.
2. After payment; receipt is been passed to web server and web server validate receipt. Is their any mechanism to get expiry date from receipt or with the help of receipt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For

- query 1: Currently i am stock to
  [Is restore button necessary for Auto-renewable subscriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524733/is-restore-button-necessary-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions)
  solution.
- and for query 2 i found that i can extract below details from
  receipt:

  1. NSString *kReceiptBundleIdentifier              = @"BundleIdentifier";
  2. NSString *kReceiptBundleIdentifierData          = @"BundleIdentifierData";
  3. NSString *kReceiptVersion                       = @"Version";
  4. NSString *kReceiptOpaqueValue                   = @"OpaqueValue";
  5. NSString *kReceiptHash                          = @"Hash";
  6. NSString *kReceiptInApp                         = @"InApp";
  7. NSString *kReceiptOriginalVersion               = @"OrigVer";
  8. NSString *kReceiptExpirationDate                = @"ExpDate";
  9. NSString *kReceiptInAppQuantity                 = @"Quantity";
  10. NSString *kReceiptInAppProductIdentifier       = @"ProductIdentifier";
  11. NSString *kReceiptInAppTransactionIdentifier   =
       @"TransactionIdentifier";
  12. NSString *kReceiptInAppPurchaseDate                = @"PurchaseDate";
  13. NSString *kReceiptInAppOriginalTransactionIdentifier   =
       @"OriginalTransactionIdentifier";
  14. NSString *kReceiptInAppOriginalPurchaseDate        =
       @"OriginalPurchaseDate";
  15. **NSString *kReceiptInAppSubscriptionExpirationDate = @"SubExpDate";**
  16. NSString *kReceiptInAppCancellationDate         = @"CancelDate";
  17. NSString *kReceiptInAppWebOrderLineItemID       = @"WebItemId";

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge on inapppurchase .. Auto-renewable subscription is acceptable for magazines ..like this only ... see the guidelines... I kept Auto-renewable for my app like webservices ...they reject my app and they suggest me to keep non-renewable subscriptions.. Now coming up to storing the receipt in your webserver .. how you can store your receipt in your webserver? based on the appleid we want to store the receipt .. but apple doesnot provide User appleid ...because all transactions is based on apple id only..i think storing the receipt is not the right way...You can keep Restore button to restore the previous transactions .. in these restore process you can get the previous transactions like product id and the transaction receipt .. you can pass this receipt to the storekit framework . then you will get the response 0 or 21006 like this based on the response you want to unlock the content...